# Excel Formula If x in column B then y, Z, K..etc in Column A

Tags: excel, formula

So basically I have a spreadsheet, with a list of names in column B. For this list of names I want to assign text to add into the adjacent cell in column A.

I have tried

```
=IF((C:C="Name1", C:C="Name2"),"Text","")
```

However, this formula gives an error without any help.

Can someone please solve this for me, or give me some information on how to solve it, as I need it to finish a project for work?

Comment: You mention column B but you have column C in your formula? Could you perhaps give an example table? (e.g. tables in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16448835/1578604)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to refine your requirements. As I understand it, you need in cell C1 and copied down

```
=IF(OR(B1="Tom",B1="Bill"),"Bill or Tom","")
```

[image]

Adjust ranges and names to suit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly

```
=if(b1="Name 1","Text","") + if(b1="Name 2","Text","")
```

If the text in cell B1 is equal to Name1 or Name2 then cell A1 (or where you choose to enter the formula) will be have "Text". If B1 does not contain Name1 or Name2 then the cell will remain empty.

Comment: Your formula is adding a text value with another text value and will return you `#VALUE!`. If you're looking for an `OR` option, you will have to modify your formula to `=if(OR(b1="Name 1",b1="Name 2"),"Text","")`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks very much for the help. I think the problem I was having was that I did not split the formula with respect to names.

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes @Jerry you are right, my bad.  I usually only use that formula with numbers.